# How do we get inquiry fields from Persona API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, persona

I am trying to extract the fields from an inquiry.

Based on the doc https://docs.withpersona.com/docs/inquiry-fields#reading-fields, it seems like that field should be present on a webhook event when "inquiry.compeleted" happens. However, I don't think that is the case.

> An inquiry's fields can be retrieved via the external API using a GET request

How exactly do we get the fields from the inquiry when theres no description on the API call at all

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by calling the `GET /api/v1/inquiries/{inquiry-id}` endpoint.

API Reference: https://docs.withpersona.com/reference/retrieve-an-inquiry

You will then find the fields in `data.attributes.fields` of the response.